# How to set a range for DHCP IP address leasing in WiFi softAP()?

Tags: arduino-ide, arduino-esp8266, esp32

I am trying to make a mesh network using ESP32 module. The WiFi.h softAPConfig() can be used to set the starting address for leasing, but it progress upwards without reusing the already leased addresses which are no more in use. So I want to limit the leasing range between two addresses.

```
I found this piece of code from dhcpserver.h 
/*   Defined in esp_misc.h */
    typedef struct {
    bool enable;
    ip4_addr_t start_ip;
    ip4_addr_t end_ip;
} dhcps_lease_t;
```

This is the code I compiled and uploaded into the ESP32 module

```
#include "WiFi.h"

char *ssid = "AirMesh";
IPAddress local_IP(192,168,1,0);
IPAddress gateway(192,168,1,1);
IPAddress subnet(255,255,255,0);

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println();

  Serial.print("Setting soft-AP configuration ... ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.softAPConfig(local_IP, gateway, subnet) ? "Ready" : "Failed!");

  Serial.print("Setting soft-AP ... ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.softAP("ESPsoftAP_01") ? "Ready" : "Failed!");

  Serial.print("Soft-AP IP address = ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.softAPIP());

  WiFi.softAP(ssid);
}

void loop() {}
```

The first device when connected gives an IP 192.168.1.1, the second device an IP 192.168.1.2, when I disconnect the first device and reconnected it and it gives an IP 192.168.1.3 (every connection use different physical addresses)
This progression keeps going

**EDIT:** 
After digging it up, I think I found the code responsible for ranging IP leasing, but couldn't figure out what it means.

```
lease.start_ip.addr = static_cast<uint32_t>(local_ip) + (1 << 24);
lease.end_ip.addr = static_cast<uint32_t>(local_ip) + (11 << 24);
```

Answer (score 0):

After trial and error methord, I managed to find the answer
Change the code in WiFiAP.cpp file (i have forked and requested a pull replacing 11 with 10 since the maximum number of connections possible for ESP32 is 10)

```
lease.start_ip.addr = static_cast<uint32_t>(local_ip) + (1 << 24);
lease.end_ip.addr = static_cast<uint32_t>(local_ip) + (n << 24);
```

Where n is number of IP addresses that must be allocated to external devices.
For ex:-

```
lease.end_ip.addr = static_cast<uint32_t>(local_ip) + (20 << 24);
```

means if the starting IP is 192.168.1.0 the DHCP will assign address starting from 192.168.1.1 to 192.168.1.20, while 192.168.1.0 (starting IP will be the address of the ESP32 module)

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't the access point use the first ip of 192.168.1.1  not 1.0?
So 2-11 is 10 connections.

Comment: Would you elaborate a bit?

Comment: This does not answer the question. Please consider posting this as a comment. You will be able to add comments when you have gain a certain amount of reputation points.

Comment: He said he is asking for a change to WiFiAP.cpp that looks ill advised. I'm not certain so I posed it as a question.   Quote                                    After trial and error methord, I managed to find the answer Change the code in WiFiAP.cpp file (i have forked and requested a pull replacing 11 with 10 since the maximum number of connections possible for ESP32 is 10)

Comment: The ESP32 access point uses 192.168.4.1 for the access point. So the next 10 leases would take from 2 to 11. Changing the max from 11 to 10 looses access to one lease.  See: https://randomnerdtutorials.com/esp32-access-point-ap-web-server/